# Android Data Binding API level check missing for setTextCursorDrawable (<=29)

Tags: android, data-binding

Since the update of Android Studio (4.2 -> Artic Fox 2020.3.1) and the update of the build tools (30.0.2 -> 31.0.0) the generated data binding class for an EditText element doesn't contain a API level check anymore.

Definition within the xml layout of the EditText

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@{null}
```

Generated code before the update:

```
// batch finished
    if ((dirtyFlags & 0x100L) != 0) {
        // api target 29
        if(getBuildSdkInt() >= 29) {
            this.editTextFirstName.setTextCursorDrawable((android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) null);
        }
    }
```

Generated code after the update:

```
// batch finished
    if ((dirtyFlags & 0x100L) != 0) {
        // api target 1
        this.editTextFirstName.setTextCursorDrawable((android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) null);            
    }
```

Remark: The generated comments state "api target 29" (before) and "api target 1" after the update.

What could be the reason for the missing API level check? The app crashes when running at devices with Android API Level <29.

Info:

- minSdkVersion 26
- targetSdkVersion 30
- compileSdkVersion 30

Comment: Did you file a bugreport?